# How do I get to Orgrimmar from Silvermoon?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm new to the Horde and I'm a death knight but I'm not quite sure how to get back to the horde main city, I'm in silvermoon city and I just don't know how to get there as dumb as it sounds, could someone help me?

Comment: I guess some alliance players don't like that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silvermoon → Undercity → Orgrimmar

Go to the north of the city into "sun fury spire", there's a room in the back called "inner sanctum", take the teleporter to "undercity" in tirisfal glades. From there you need to go out of the city and take a zepelin. There are several zeppelin towers, you need to take the one that goes to orgrimmar. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-to-Orgrimmar-from-Undercity-Fast-on-World-of-Warcraft) is a guide of how to get from undercity to orgrimmar.

You can always ask someone in general or trade chat about this kind of thing.